# Background image not loading in Electron Application

Tags: html, css, webpack, vue.js, electron

I have an image file in the same directory as my login.vue component (which is where the following code is located). But, when I try this code, the image will not load:

```
<div background="benjamin-child-17946.jpg" class="login" style="height:100%;">
```

I'm getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is strange, because I can see in my terminal that my image is in the same directory as login.vue. I am using webpack to compile. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary issue is that single file components are compiled and the compiled script is very unlikely to reside in the same directory as the current location as your image. Your second issue is that you are not assigning the background image to your `div` correctly. You should use CSS.

I would suggest that you make an `images` directory in the root of your electron application (or assets or static or whatever you want to call it). Then, you can reference files in that directory using the `file://` protocol.

Second, I would recommend you define a CSS class and use that. So, in your single file component, define this style section:

```
<style>
  .background {
    background: url('file:///images/benjamin-child-17946.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover
  }
</style>
```

And on your div just use the class.

```
<div class="login background">
```

Finally, you could also use webpack's `url-loader` to load the file as a `dataUrl` but I would recommend that as a more advanced exercise and just stick with the simple method for now.

**Edit**

I created a project from scratch using [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) which uses webpack and I did run into an error with the above using the `file://` protocol, that I don't run into when not using webpack. With the above template, instead of using
`file:///images/benjamin-child-17946.jpg`, put the file in the `static` directory and use `/static/benjamin-child-17946.jpg`. That allows `vue-loader` to work properly.

If you are not using `electron-vue`, then your webpack configuration may be different.

Comment: So I put the image in an images directory inside of my apps root directory but I was met with a "Not allowed to load local resource error"

Comment: @randyMoss1994 there is a long thread [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5107) about resolving that error, particularly about using webpack with electron. Is your code available on GitHub or somewhere?

Comment: @randyMoss1994 did you start with a template?

Comment: I used templates in all VUE components but not in my main index.ejs file

Comment: @randyMoss1994 Thats not what I meant, sorry. I meant, did you start the Vue project with a template like `electron-vue`? If so, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Bert yeah I'm using electron-vue

Comment: @randyMoss1994 did this answer your questions?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help Bert!

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that background is not a valid HTML attribute anymore.

Compiled VUE code doesn't match the way the folders are built, assuming you're using the CLI.

You would need to reference the images full URL in its static resource location.

I'm not sure what that would be in this case as I haven't used static resources with the Vue CLI yet.