# "Not allowed to load local resource" Electron/VUE

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, electron

So I am receiving the error "Not allowed to load local resource" in my Electron/VUE app. The error I believe is coming from my index.ejs file where I have

```
<style>
 .background{
  background: url('file:///images-benjamin-child-17946.jpg') no repeat center center fixed;
 background-size cover;
}
</style>
```

the image benjamin-child is located in the images folder which should have a path something like: electronApp/app/images

Installing/running the app is easy you can just follow the README.md.

Comment: You should look at the edit to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532621/background-image-not-loading-in-electron-application/44533162#44533162

Comment: Hey Bert Evans, So I looked at the edit I made the change to /static/benjamin-child-17946.jpg but now I get "Failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at that repo, and in this case, if you just copy the image file into the dist directory and use

```
background: url('/benjamin-child-17946.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

it should work. Presumably there is a webpack setup that will copy files from the `static` directory in the app to `dist` for you.