# react + electron app issue > failed to load resource: net::err_file_not_found bg.jpg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

when i  build the electron app without using local server or trying to packaging the app with electron-packager, it shows me

> Blockquote failed to load resource: net::err_file_not_found  bg.jpg

however when i use local server "express" the app runs just fine.
how can i resolve that problem to package the app with all resources

**this is the webpack.config**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.test' });
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.development' });
}

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProduction = env === 'production';
  const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

  return {
    target:"electron-renderer",
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist',),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }, {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: CSSExtract.extract({
         // publicPath:'./',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      }]
    },
    plugins: [
      CSSExtract
    ],
    devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      publicPath: '/dist/'
    }
  };
};
```

**and this is the Index.js of electron**

```
//import electronGoogleOauth from 'electron-google-oauth';
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const url = require('url');

// Module to control application life.

// Module to create native browser window.
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const ipc = electron.ipcMain;
const shell = electron.shell;
// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;
let workerWindow;


/** This function will create the mainWindow */
function createWindow() {
  console.log('hello world')

  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    width: 950,
    height: 750,
    'minHeight':700,
    'minWidth': 950,
    icon:path.join(__dirname,'./src/assets/icons/icon.ico'),
   });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  //mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/public/index.html');
  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/public/index.html');

  ////////////////////////////////////////// Invisible Window //////////
  workerWindow = new BrowserWindow();
    workerWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/worker.html`);
    //workerWindow.hide();
    workerWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    workerWindow.on("closed", () => {
        workerWindow = undefined;
    });

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    const {
      default: installExtension,
      REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS,
      REDUX_DEVTOOLS,
    } = require('electron-devtools-installer'); // eslint-disable-line
    installExtension(REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS)
      .then(name => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
      .catch(err => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));

    installExtension(REDUX_DEVTOOLS)
      .then(name => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
      .catch(err => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
  }

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

ipc.on("printPDF",(event, content) => {
    workerWindow.webContents.send("printPDF", content);
});


// when worker window is ready
ipc.on("readyToPrintPDF", (event) => {
  const pdfPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'print.pdf');
  // Use default printing options
  workerWindow.webContents.printToPDF({}, function (error, data) {
      if (error) throw error
      fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, function (error) {
          if (error) {
              throw error
          }
    console.log(2)
          shell.openItem(pdfPath)
          event.sender.send('wrote-pdf', pdfPath)

      })
  })

});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ipc.on('print-to-pdf', function(event){
  const pdfPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(),'print.pdf');
  const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender);
  win.webContents.printToPDF({},function(error,data){
    if(error) return console.log(error.message)
    fs.writeFile(pdfPath,data, function(err){
      if(err)return console.log(err.message);
      shell.openExternal('file://'+pdfPath);
      event.sender.send('wrote-pdf',pdfPath)
    })
  })
})
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

**Index.html**

```
    <html> 
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>My electron app</title>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/styles.css" />
    </head>

<body style="-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;">
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is bg.jpg used? it doesn't appear in the code provided.

Comment: its in css file, inside styles folder 
.box-layout {
  align-items: center;
  background:url('/public/images/bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
}

Comment: here is a screenshot >>  https://image.ibb.co/dzxi3y/screen.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background image not loading in Electron Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532621/background-image-not-loading-in-electron-application)

Comment: Have you tried adding the `file:///` prefix to the path of the image in your CSS?

Comment: Thank you Mr Randy,  but the background does load when i use local express server and load the app with "mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/public/index.html');" , but when i load the app through 
mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/public/index.html`) 
it throws the issue of  "failed to load resource: net::err_file_not_found bg.jpg"

Comment: Thank you Neil , i have tried your suggestion and it did work , i got an error in while compiling >
    ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMa
p":true}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js
?{"sourceMap":true}!./src/styles/styles.scss
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './file:///images/bg.jpg'